# $ngCordova BLE plugin is undefined on iOS

Tags: ios, cordova, ionic-framework

I am working on connecting my iOS 5c v9.3.2 to my arduino uno with the blefruit add on. I am working on an Ionic project with the most recent version of ionic and cordova installed. I tried installed ngCordova, and included the `cordova-plugin-ble-central` to my plugins. I injected $cordovaBLE as I saw a few other examples show, but it was just an empty object when I ran the following code within the controller: `alert(JSON.stirngify($cordovaBLE));` I also tried that with `ble` but it did not show a message. I believe that `ble` is undefined and because of that, the `$cordovaBLE` could not properly create it's functions. Is anyone else having this issue or might be able to help?

Answer (score 0):

I tried creating a new project in ionic and setting it up as I had above, and this time when I used the `ble` to call my functions and copied the code directly from it's readme.md, it worked. I was passing an object where I should have been passing a success callback.